# How to delete all member accounts with no channel entries

Tags: members, spam

Any EE folks know if there is a way to delete all member accounts that have no channel entries assigned to them?

In my case any accounts with 0 entries would be spam.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're comfortable doing this directly in the database, these are SQL queries that delete all members who are not authors of channel entries:

```
delete from exp_members where member_id not in (select author_id from exp_channel_titles);

delete from exp_member_data where member_id not in (select author_id from exp_channel_titles);

delete from exp_member_homepage where member_id not in (select author_id from exp_channel_titles)
```

Be sure to backup your database first!!! Just in case.

(Also, I assume you meant "authors" when you describe entries assigned to members. Is this correct?)

Comment: yes, authors is correct, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all those members with single SQL:

```
DELETE exp_members, exp_member_data, exp_member_homepage FROM exp_members 
INNER JOIN exp_member_data 
INNER JOIN exp_member_homepage 
WHERE exp_member_data.member_id = exp_members.member_id 
AND exp_members.member_id = exp_member_homepage.member_id 
AND exp_members.total_entries = 0
```

I would suggest you to take database backup first.