# How to clear member accounts with no entries after 6 months

Tags: members, database

I had asked a similar question a while back:
[How to delete all member accounts with no channel entries](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13810/how-to-delete-all-member-accounts-with-no-channel-entries)

Need a slightly different twist.

I need to remove member accounts that have authored no channel entries AND were created 6 months ago or older.

I could use some help writing the date part of the query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT
    member_id,
    username,
    join_date,
    now(),
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - (86400 * 30 * 6))
FROM
    exp_members
WHERE
    join_date < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - (86400 * 30 * 6))
```

Returns members who have a join date older than 15552000 seconds (about 6 months).